# vim auto close $$ and \[\] in the insert mode?

Tags: vim, auto-close

I am using vim-latex to edit tex files and often type inline math formula by `$xxxx$` and displaymath environment by `\[xxxx\].` In the visual mode, Vim-latex provide shortcuts for them, i.e. `$ ,depending on characterwise or linewise selection.

How to implement auto close for them in the insert mode and let the cursor left between them? (I have used delimitMate for auto-closing, but it doesn't provide this type auto-closing.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use Snipmate or Ultisnips for that but you can do:

```
inoremap $$ $$<Left>
inoremap \[ \[\]<Left><Left>
```